# HTML Writing in TCPDF library

Tags: php, web-services, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have 104 html paragraphs which are entered into my db using a text editor. Some paragraphs take one or one and half pages and some takes only few lines. When I try to generate a pdf for the whole set, it gives me 'Server error' , but when i try to print few paragraphs it does a good job. Then i tried increasing the paragraph count one by one and i got stuck with 85 paragraphs. After that it gives me server error. Does anyone know how to fix this issue ? because i got another set of  html tables other than these paragraphs. 
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To properly help you, we really need to see the code you're dealing with, within the question (at least enough to fully understand the problem, but not your entire codebase). It *seems* like you're running out of memory, so checking the code for any ridiculously inefficient or subtly inefficient methods you may be using is perhaps the broad answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a case of time limit for execution

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

if you add this in the code , max execution time is set to unlimited and TCPDF can process all paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

I checked the server error log file, then i found the error,it was "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /XXXXXXX/includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 5036" . So i set execution time using

```
set_time_limit(180);
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your server isn't running out of memory.. TCPDF can use alot of memory when rendering

Try

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

in your php.ini file..

Comment: My error was with "time limit for execution" but I didn't consider about my memory also i will check that too. Thanks for the help !